# Trable with compressed merged css files

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I want to compress the merged css using Apptrain Minify HTML, CSS, JS, but I have the following problem: as soon as a new session starts (a new user comes in or I get a new request), the merged css is overwritten and again not compressed. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: or can have another solution for compression other than gzip